# How to get data from API and insert in SQL Server tables using Talend

Tags: sql-server-2012, etl, talend, data-transfer

I am new to Talend and just know basic knowledge on it. I have previously created jobs in Talend which use to transfer data from file/database to file/database. But this time I need to create a job in Talend for which the data needs to be taken from an API and needs to be inserted in the SQL Server tables. Please help me in getting data from API and inserted in DB tables!

I think I might need to use tESBConsumer...but not sure how to proceed.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Talend you can use components that will allow you to connect to your SQL Server table. So what I suggest is to take an SQL Server component available in the Palette (type SQL Server in the search bar) or even review all of them on the Talend components page https://www.talendforge.org/components/

Here is a screenshot of some of the components available for SQL Server:
[image: Components page]

Let us know if you have additional questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot..but my question is how to get the data from a web service and then based on the response, feed the SQL table with it??

Comment: So you would like to utilize a web service: which type is or what's the name of your web service? You could use the tESBconsumer component or your web service's component available in the Palette. And then connect that component to the SQL component to load the resulting data in the database. The design would look like this: Web service -> web service component -> SQL component -> SQL table